# GroupBy and Sort_values sum

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe with columns such as "Apples sold every day" "Melons sold every day", and columns "normal", with no mean values, such as strawberries sold

| seller | Apples sold every day | Melons sold every day | Strawberries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| C | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| D | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| D | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| E | 2 | 1 | 0 |

I have to filter to see each seller how many apples he has sold, how mant melons he has sold and how many Strawberries in a whole month, in a ranking from the best to the worst seller

For the Strawberries, this code it's working well

```
dfFruit.groupby('seller').sum()[['Strawberries']].sort_values(['Strawberries'], ascending = [False]).head(10)
```

For apples and melons no, of course, because I think the code does the sum between each values and, for ex, in this case I think it returns: D 10 apples, C 4, A 3, B 3 and so on.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

| Seller | Apple sold |
| --- | --- |
| D | 5 |
| C | 4 |
| B | 3 |
| E | 2 |
| A | 1 |

The same for Melons sold

Comment: Python doesn't have data frames, are you talking about pandas?

Comment: Yes, sorry, Pandas

Comment: What should be the expected output for your sample?

Comment: Ok, so what you are looking for is `first` or `mean` instead of `sum`. You can check my answer.

Comment: I don't know why it gave me error but I solved putting max instead of sum. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is not clear. If you don't want to `sum` on all columns, use `groupby_agg`:

```
out = (df.groupby('seller', as_index=False)
         .agg({'Apples sold every day': 'first',
               'Melons sold every day': 'first',
               'Strawberries': 'sum'})
         .sort_values('Strawberries', ascending=False))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
 seller  Apples sold every day  Melons sold every day  Strawberries
0      A                      1                      3             7
1      B                      3                      4             4
2      C                      4                      1             3
3      D                      5                      2             3
4      E                      2                      1             0
```

**EDIT**:
To get the expected output:

```
out = (df.groupby('seller')['Apples sold every day'].first()
         .sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
  seller  Apples sold every day
0      D                      5
1      C                      4
2      B                      3
3      E                      2
4      A                      1
```